# put seperator after each 10 digits

Tags: javascript, html

In a HTML input field user can put as many mobile numbers as he wants say(5)
Each mobile number consists of 10 digit numbers and i want to put a separator after each mobile number entered by a user. Something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#editMobile").on('keyup',function () {
        var key = $(this).val();
        this.num = 10
        if(key.length == this.num){

            $("#editMobile").val(key+";");

            this.num = this.num+10;
        }

     });
});
```

this code works well for first 10 digits.

Please help me to extend this code for more than one mobile number

Thanks.
Sunil

Comment: What happens if someone enters their mobile number beginning with the country code, e.g. +31

Comment: Did you try the answer @sunil ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `if` condition like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#editMobile").on('keyup',function () {
        var key = $(this).val();
        if(key.length % 10 == 0){  // Check this condition. It will divide by 10 and if reminder is 0 then add separater.

            $("#editMobile").val(key+";");
        }

     });
});
```

Comment: It would add `;` for each 10 numbers length.

Comment: on each `keyup` it will take the current value of the input and check if length is % 10 ? If it would be then it will append `;` to the whatever value is there in `key` variable.

Comment: Won't there be an issue with `%10` with the semi-colon being added after every 10 characters? After 10 key-presses a semi-colon would be added, after 9 key-presses the next semi-colon would be added since `%10` would include the previous semi-colon... and a whole variety of oddness could happen if someone went back and amended something they'd previously entered earlier in the string. I like the approach but it seems like it'll be badly prone to bugs.

Comment: yes, @CD001, you are right. I did not think about it. Can you think of a better way?

Comment: I'd probably just tell the user to enter a comma separated list :D